# Unable to create user from "scott" account with granted DBA

Tags: oracle

Currently, playing around with Oracle DB 11g on Windows XP. Logged in as scott user (not sysdba) with granted DBA role. According to Oracle docs "DBA  = All system privileges WITH ADMIN OPTION". Why then creation of a new user gives error "ORA-01031 insufficient privileges..."? Here's DDL command executed using SQL Developer:

```
CREATE USER john identified by 123
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [`document`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96521/privs.htm#14895) for SET ROLE and default role

To enable all roles granted to you for the current session, issue the following statement:

SET ROLE ALL;

Or modify user default role

ALTER USER scott DEFAULT ROLE ALL;